# Unable to install symfony2 OSExcelBundle bundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to integrate OSExcelBundle plugin in my Symfony2 project.
I have followed the README tutorial and which mentions the following

```
Add this line to the require option in your composer.json file:

 "os/excel-bundle": "dev-master"

Add autoloader for PHPExcel in app/autoloader.php

 require __DIR__.'/../vendor/os/php-excel/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

Execute this command line

 php composer.phar install
```

in order to be able to be able to execute the php command line i had to download composer from http://www.getcomposer.org and place the executable within the bundle. When i run it, i have the following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for os/excel-bundle == 1.0.0.0 -> satisfiable by os/excel-bundle 1.0.0.
- Can only install one of: os/excel-bundle dev-master, os/excel-bundle 1.0.0.
- Installation request for os/excel-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by os/excel-bundle dev-master.
```

Here are the other steps i've been going through in order to install the symfony2 plugin

1 - I placed the plugin in the vendor/bundle directory so it match the following path

```
vendor/bundle/OS/ExcelBundle
```

2 - I have added this line to the app/AppKernel.php file

```
new OS\ExcelBundle\OSExcelBundle(),
```

3 - I followed the README from above

Here is the Json

```
{
  "name": "os/excel-bundle",
  "description": "OS Excel Bundle for Symfony2",
  "keywords": ["excel"],
  "homepage": "http://github.com/ouardisoft/OSExcelBundle",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "LOUARDI Abdeltif",
      "email": "louardi.abdeltif@yahoo.fr",
      "homepage": "http://phphub.net"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.6",
    "os/php-excel": "dev-master",
    "os/excel-bundle": "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "psr-0": { "OS\\ExcelBundle": "" }
  },
  "target-dir": "OS/ExcelBundle"
}
```

Comment: How many times does os/excel-bundle show up in your composer.json file?

Comment: 2 times here. I am adding the Json

Comment: That looks like the composer file for the bundle, what does the file for your project say (do you have one)? Which version of Symfony are you using 2.0 or 2.1? The Symfony 2.0 standard edition doesnt use Composer, it uses a deps file.

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony 2.0 standard edition doesnt use composer, it uses a deps file and vendor script. Read through [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#cookbook-managing-vendor-libraries)

You need to add the vendor library to your projects deps file and run `php bin/vendors install` to get it installed into your vendor folder.

Alternatively upgrade to 2.1, and you can use Composer.

Comment: I have chosen the option of installing the 2.1 version which comes with composer. I have been going again through the same process but in the end i have the same probelm. Nevertheless i noticed that the problem might come from the fact that i include the "os/excel-bundle": "dev-master" line in the json as the readme suggest. Because without this line, composer runs fine. And since i don't know how important this line is, i am not sure the plugin is going to work. Got to try!